# How to add lucide-angular to the standalone Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add [lucide-icon](https://lucide.dev/) package to my standalone Angular app. [Accroding to it's document](https://lucide.dev/guide/packages/lucide-angular#step-1-import-lucideangularmodule) it's availabe for the Angular module but I'm using standalone mode, so how to add this package to the component?

I tried this way but it gives me error.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { NgClass, NgOptimizedImage } from '@angular/common';
import { cx } from 'class-variance-authority';
import { LucideAngularModule, Home } from 'lucide-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, NgOptimizedImage, NgClass, LucideAngularModule.pick({Home})],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'tasko';
  protected readonly cx = cx;
}
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: You always can add to a module and import this new module in your standalone component. BTW if you're using standaloneComponent with routes see that you need use [https://angular.io/api/router/provideRouter](https://angular.io/api/router/provideRouter),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of the implementation, we need to use `importProvidersFrom` and get the providers from the main module, using the below code!

```
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(LucideAngularModule.pick({ Home }))],
});
```

To use the components (`lucide-angular`) we need to directly import the module in the component imports!

```
...
imports: [LucideAngularModule],
...
```

full code

```
import { Component, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LucideAngularModule, Home } from 'lucide-angular';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [LucideAngularModule],
  template: `
    <lucide-angular name="home" class="my-icon"></lucide-angular>
    <lucide-icon name="home" class="my-icon"></lucide-icon>
    <i-lucide name="home" class="my-icon"></i-lucide>
    <span-lucide name="home" class="my-icon"></span-lucide>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [importProvidersFrom(LucideAngularModule.pick({ Home }))],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yoxlin?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)